# Setup Ad-hoc WIFI from terminal in OS X

Tags: mac-osx, wifi, adhoc-network

Is it possible to create a Ad-hoc Wifi network in OS X using the command line? Without using Apple Script to do it through the UI.

Answer (score 3):

I've used `sudo /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -i[<arg>]` to do the job.  Take a look at `/usr/sbin/networksetup` to round out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As a newer answer for making an ad hoc network that works in Mojave without a internet connection, while searching online, I finally found an answer!

Smoooosher's answer only works with an active connection to share.

To create your own "active" network, in terminal run the 2 following commands.

```
sudo networksetup -createnetworkservice Loopback lo0
sudo networksetup -setmanual Loopback 172.20.42.42 255.255.255.255
```

This creates a new network conection that although it looks inactive, it can be shared from the internet sharing preference pane to wifi.